# Does Python's os.path.getsize() have true byte resolution?

Tags: python, filesize, disk

File systems rarely allow files to be arbitrary numbers of bytes long, instead preferring to pad them to fit in a certain number of blocks. Python's os.path.getsize() is documented to return a size in units of bytes, but I am not sure whether or not it is rounded by the OS (linux, in my case) or filesystem, to a block size. For my application it is necessary that I know the exact number of bytes that I will be able to read out of a large file (~1GB). What guarantees are made about this?

Comment: This depends on your filesystem. Some filesystems (like procfs and sysfs) don't return a nonzero size in stat data at all. If you want complete certainty, open the file, `seek()` to the end, and use `tell()` to give you the current offset. That said, for a regular file on commonly-available filesystems used for regular (not generated, not virtual, not socket, not block device) files, `os.path.getsize()` will return what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No guarantees are made by Python. The `os.path.getsize()` function returns the  [`st_size` field of a `os.stat()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat). This is a direct call to the [`stat` system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)).

All the documentation for `stat` simply names `st_size` as the file size, in bytes.

On my Debian test system `stat` gives true filesizes:

```
$ stat -fc %s .   # fs block size
4096
$ head -c 2048 < /dev/urandom > 2kb
$ head -c 6168 < /dev/urandom > 6kb
$ head -c 12345 < /dev/urandom > 12andabitkb
$ ls --block-size=1 -s *kb     # block use in bytes
16384 12andabitkb   4096 2kb   8192 6kb
$ ls --block-size=4K -s *kb    # block count per file
4 12andabitkb  1 2kb  2 6kb
$ python3 -c 'import os, glob; print(*("{:<11} {}".format(f, os.path.getsize(f)) for f in glob.glob("*kb")), sep="\n")'
2kb         2048
12andabitkb 12345
6kb         6168
```